# How to get the password of an user in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack

How to get the **password** of an existing user in **Rabbitmq** from CLI?
I got the name of the user by CLI command "*sudo rabbitmqctl list_users*" and the outupt is as follows:

> *Listing users ... guest  [administrator] openstack   []*

I want to know the '**openstack**' user password.

Comment: Why don't you just set the password to something you know?

Comment: @theMayer can you tell the CLI commands for setting it?

Answer (score 8):

The user passwords are stored using a one-way hash so there is no way to retrieve their value. You should use the `rabbitmqctl change_password` command to change that user's password to a known value.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a deployment solution you might find the password in it's configuration. For example, when you deploy Openstack using kolla-ansible you find the password in `/etc/kolla/passwords.yml`.

```
user@deployhost:~$ grep -E ^rabbitmq_password: /etc/kolla/passwords.yml
rabbitmq_password: haH2ZPjVVKmiqoXdRPCYJcdQyzP2cqeU
```

It might be stored in some secure way, for example an vault if ansible is used for deployment, in this case you need to check the deployment framework on how to retrieve it.